# Passing multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array

I wrote the following code. It works great, but I have a question (so I don't bomb any future additions). Here's the code:

```
public class MoreStuff extends javax.swing.JFrame {

// Globals
int quiz[][]; // Used for Quiz subroutines


...


private void btnGetQuizActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    Functions fns = new Functions(); 
    String strout;
    int i = 0;

    // Get the quiz
    quiz = fns.GetQuiz();
```

The fns.GetQuiz() returns a 2-dimensional array perfectly.

My question is this: Having declared a multidimensional array at the class level, when the computer executes quiz = fns.GetQuiz, have I passed an object or have I only copied a reference?

Comment: `quiz` receives a copy of the reference to the array.

Comment: @sstan - Okay, but here's what I don't get -- After the code finishes executing in btnGetQuizActionPerformed, I'm guessing the object fns (where GetQuiz and its variables are stored) is destroyed. If quiz is getting a copy of a reference to an array that has been destroyed, how am I still able to pluck values out of the quiz array when the user clicks a different button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `GetQuiz()`'s implementation is simply:

```
public int[][] GetQuiz() {
    int[][] someArray = new int[10][];
    return someArray;
}
```

The line `int[][] someArray = new int[10][];` allocates an array on the heap and assigns a reference to that object to `someArray`.

When the method `GetQuiz()` finishes executing, the only thing "destroyed" is `someArray`, which is simply the reference to the array.  The array itself lives on the heap, and only becomes eligible for garbage collection once there are no more references to the array.

In your example, because a copy of the reference is assigned to the `quiz` variable, even when `someArray` is destroyed, you still have `quiz`'s reference pointing to the array, so the garbage collector will not try to destroy the array.

I think you might find the information in this thread helpful: [Stack and Heap memory in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java).

Comment: Hey, thanks for spelling that one out and especially the link.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, `quiz` will hold its value even after the execution of `btnGetQuizActionPerformed()` because it receives a copy of the reference to`fns`.